# Push notification badges not appearing?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I'm using Urban Airship to send push notifications to my app

eg:

```
{"aps": {"badge": 2, "alert": "Part 2 of the August Issue is ready to download!", "sound": "default"}, "device_tokens": ["X"]}
```

The alert will display perfectly, however the app icon is never badged regardless of what I set "badge":# to...

Is my payload incorrect or is there extra code I'm supposed to add to my app to handle badges as well as alerts? Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm registering for push notifications like this:

```
// Register for notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the following code in the appdelegate .m file..

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{


    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    //[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo];

    NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"my message-- %@",alertValue);
    int badgeValue= [alertValue intValue];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeValue];

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was running with a similar problem. After a few minutes of checking around. I notice that there was a problem with my server side code. I found out that badge value has to be implicitly set as an integer to get the desired result. Hope that helps anyone reading this.

Comment: I guess this means it should be passed as 4 instead of "4".

Comment: Awesome find! Thanks.

Comment: @Joqn Yes, thats correct. It should be passed as a 4 and not "4".

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 5 there is a Settings -> Notifications. Double check that the Badge App Icon is turned on.

I assume that the app is not in the foreground when you were testing? It if is in the foreground then you have to handle badging manually.

Comment: Badges are enabled in settings for my app, also badges do not appear regardless of foreground, background or fresh launch...